# text detection from an image with perspective distortion using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, ocr, matlab-cvst

Can anyone know different methods for text detection from an image with perspective distortion using matlab or any code is available.Is opencv is better than matlab for text detection

Answer (score 2):

I think, matlab is good for text detection (ocr). 
There ara a few libraries for ocr. Most important ones are :

- Abbyy
- [Tesseract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract_%28software%29)

Tesseract is considered one of the most accurate open source OCR engines currently available.

I have worked on ocr with perspective distortion and i use [matlab-tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/matlab-tesseract-ocr/) library.

I have handle perspective distorsion problem with rotate image by finding image border and its lines with [houghlines](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/houghlines.html) method.

I will share my code snippet and i hope it gives you a vision about that issue

```
        function [ output_args ] = rotate_image(  )
         clc;
         close all;
         clear; 

         I = imread("any_images")
         I2 = imcrop(I,[85 150 590 480]);
         I3 = imcrop(I2,[-85 0 440 480]);
         imwrite (I3,'original.tiff', 'Resolution', 300);
        thresh = graythresh(I3);
        Bimage = im2bw(I3, thresh);
        Bimage = edge(Bimage,'sobel');
        [H, T, R] = hough(Bimage);%,'RhoResolution',0.1,'Theta',[-90,0]);
        P  = houghpeaks(H,10);%,'threshold',ceil(0.3*max(H(:))));
        % Find lines and plot them
        lines = houghlines(Bimage,T,R,P);%,'FillGap',100,'MinLength',5);
        figure, imshow(I3), hold on
        max_len = 0;
        for k = 1:length(lines)
            xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
            len = norm(lines(k).point1 - lines(k).point2);
            if ( len > max_len)
                max_len = len;
                xy_long = xy;
            end
        end

    % highlight the longest line segment
    plot(xy_long(:,1),xy_long(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','blue');
    a = -xy_long(1,1) + xy_long(2,1);    
    b = -xy_long(1,2) + xy_long(2,2);

    angle=180-atand(b/a);

    if angle > 180
        angle = angle-180;
    end

    angle
    B = imresize(I3, 2);

   if angle > 90
        B =  imrotate(B, 90 - angle ,'bilinear','crop');
   else 
        B =  imrotate(B, -angle,'bilinear','crop');
   end

   imwrite (B,'rotated_image.tiff', 'Resolution', 300);

 end
```

Comment: hai  can you give the image also pls Is this code is applicable for video sequence

Comment: No its not for video sequence. It just picks a snapshot from camera. I will edit my code.

Comment: thankyou sir ..Do you know how to detect the maximal stable extreme region of an image using matlab or how to add c program to matlab code